# Updated to realm 0.89.1 and now I get an error while trying to clear from db

Tags: android, database, realm

I have this code:

```
try{ 
  realm.beginTransaction();
  realm.where(UserRecord.class).findAll().clear();
  realm.commitTransaction();
  realm.beginTransaction();
  userRecord = realm.createObjectFromJson(UserRecord.class, response.responseString);
  realm.commitTransaction();
  PSUserService.getInstance(getActivity()).addToList(userRecord);
  PSLocationCenter.getInstance().pref.setUserId(getActivity(), String.valueOf(userRecord.getId()));
} catch (Exception e){
  Log.i("","============== realm errorr is" + e.getMessage());
}
```

And I get this response:

```
04-29 16:18:38.699: I/(23949): ============== realm error in this method is not supported by RealmResults.
```

When it gets at `realm.where(UserRecord.class).findAll().clear();` I saw this is deprecated. but what can I use instead? (The documentation still shows clear)

Comment: BTW: you got error in word "error" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `clear()` used to do:

> Removes all objects from the list.

you may now use `deleteAllFromRealm()` instead:

> This deletes all objects in the collection from the underlying Realm as well as from the collection.

I agree that depreciation message could be more descriptive. Please consider filling a bug report against their documentation: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues